# ANTLR4 runtime problem in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, antlr4

I'm trying to get antlr working in VS. I’ve not touched VS for a very long time. I've added the AntlrVSIX extension per the Antlr online docs, this created a sample calculator project for me but I can't compile it (I uninstalled and reinstalled AntlrVSIX but it made no difference to the following problem).

VS complains “The type or namespace name 'Antlr4' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)” and points to the line “using Antlr4.Runtime.Misc;” (and lots more similar).

If I look in menu Tools:NuGet Package Manager:Manage NuGetPackages for Solution… it clearly shows Antlr4.Runtime.Standard present and installed (showing version 4.8.0).

I guess I have to add a reference to this dll to my project so I I right click on References:Add Reference... in Solutions Explorer but I can’t find it in any list, however I search.

There is a Browse button which I assume I could use to link to the DLL directly, so I’ve searched the disk, found the dll and linked to that. This now works in that all those errors go away, but this can’t possibly be the right way.

So how do you add a reference to it properly, using References:Add Reference...? VS knows it’s there, it displays it, but doesn’t let it be referenced like that because it won’t show it within VS via References:Add Reference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your specific question, yes, you don't want to add a reference to the dll. Instead, you need to add a "<PackageReference>" in the csproj for these dependencies. All this lives in Nuget.org. So, in VS2019, right click on a project in the Solution Manager, then look for "Manage Nuget packages" to add Antlr4BuildTasks and Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.

Note, I've been updating the Antlrvsix extension, but haven't made a release for 2 months, longer than my usual schedule, because the next version has a huge number of changes. I will be cutting version 8 in a week. The template in VS2019 was removed because it is old and out of date. It uses an ancient version of the Antlr4BuildTasks. Instead, use the Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates v8.1 to create a C# project from scratch. Please follow the directions [here](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks/tree/master/Templates). You don't need to download the Antlr tool kit, Java, or set any environmental variables. You also don't even need to use VS2019. You only need Net Core 3.1 and to install Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates. Then, type "mkdir foo; cd foo; dotnet new antlr; dotnet restore; dotnet build; dotnet run" at a command-line shell to create a C# application with Antlr4. Once you create the application, you can modify that to what you need. If you start from a Net Standard or Net Core project that doesn't have Antlr yet, you will need to add in the project reference for Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.8 and Antlr4BuildTasks 8.1, add in all grammars, and driver to set up and call the parser--harder to do, but it can be done through VS, or you can edit the CSPROJ file more easily and faster. The Antlr4BuildTasks looks at your CSPROJ file and will see that Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.8 is referenced, then will use the correct version of the Antlr JAR file to generate the parser and lexer. Any questions, let me know.

Comment: Wahey, that worked! As I spent 10 hours or more browsing articles trying to get this to work, can I PLEASE suggest that this valuable answer go somewhere on the main antlr FAQ? Also I have a little feedback which I'd like to pass on in private - I can do this on the github antlr issues if you'd like. And thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, the doc and tools for C# are fractured. A note should be placed in Antlr.org ([here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/csharp-target.md)), but as my tools are not official Antlr code, it may not get in. I've worked hard to make a seamless program template and build for C# Antlr programs using the official Antlr tool, and that builds under VS, VSCode, Rider, or on the command line with dotnet.exe, and which is also completely separate from the extension you may want to use to support the Antlr grammar in an editor. Feel free to add issues in github for the tools.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Antlr4.CodeGenerator NuGet package, it's gonna generated all necessary files (visitors, listeners) to work with your grammar in antlr. Check out [my article](https://medium.com/@konstantin.poklonskiy/how-to-create-your-own-language-with-antlr-in-net-a57beba84ecc) for the details, there is a link to Github repo with the solution that works in VS 2019.

Comment: Antlr4BuildTasks is a drop-in replacement for Antlr4.CodeGenerator (see [how to convert](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks#conversion-from-antlr4codegeneratorantlr4runtime-to-antlr4buildtasksantlr4runtimestandard)). I forked it from Harwell's great tool and it works identically. The reason for the fork is that Harwell's code is three years out of date and, AFAIK, not maintained. Antlr4BuildTasks calls the 4.8 Antlr tool, offering all plus more. It includes a small JRE and the antlr-4.8-complete.jar, but, if needed, downloads older versions of the tool for Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.

Comment: @konstantin: I just needed clear instructions. Ken's package isn't at fault, just lack of docs. I hope to help with that. I've got it working now, am fine. BTW your article uses painfully small font for code, and doesn't state up-front what language it is (guess t's c#). But nice article, thanks!